# Putting dictionary values into data frame new column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dictionary with key and values and I wish to create a new pandas data frame object with a new column constructed from dictionary values only. Whats is the most optimised way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add sample? Maybe works simple `df = pd.DataFrame(d)`

Comment: For example, I have a dictionary as name (key) and score(value) [tom:100, jerry:150, micky:400, donald:250] Now all I want is a data frame with column name as "scores" having all scores(values) from this dictionary.
Say like df['scores'] = ...

Comment: No, *put the example in the original question not in a comment*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
d = {'tom':100, 'jerry':150, 'micky':400, 'donald':250}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df.columns = ['scores']
print (df)
        scores
micky      400
donald     250
jerry      150
tom        100
```

Another solution is add `dict` with new column name to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'scores':d})

print (df)
        scores
donald     250
jerry      150
micky      400
tom        100
```

Last if need remove names from index add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.reset_index(drop=True))
   scores
0     400
1     250
2     150
3     100
```

Another solution is use only `values` of `dict`, but python dictionaries are always unordered, so get random order of values in `df`:

```
print (d.values())
dict_values([400, 250, 150, 100])

#python 3 add list
df = pd.DataFrame({'scores': list(d.values())})
print (df)
   scores
0     400
1     250
2     150
3     100
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for your quick reply. I wish to achieve outcome as shown by your last step - without names. I am looking for an optimised way to achieve this as my example was a small dataset. What if we have a huge dataset and yet we first load whole dictionary into data frame and then drop names. Can we directly load values into data frame?

Comment: I add last solution, I believe it can be fastest.